# Getting coordinates in both decimal degrees and meters in ArcGIS attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table

I have an attribute table of points and the coordinates are stated in decimal degrees. I would like to add two fields where the coordinates are also stated in meters or kilometers. I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

To do this just add new fields for the meters and kilometres values, and then use the [Calculate Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000027000000) tool to update them:

> The Calculate Geometry tool allows you to access the geometry of the
>   features in a layer. The tool can calculate coordinate values,
>   lengths, and areas, depending on the geometry of the input layer. You
>   can only calculate the area, length, or perimeter of features if the
>   coordinate system being used is projected. Keep in mind that different
>   projections have different spatial properties and distortions. If the
>   coordinate system of the data source and data frame are not the same,
>   you may get a different result if you calculate geometry using the
>   data frame's coordinate system than when you calculate using the data
>   source's coordinate system. It is recommended that an equal-area
>   projection be used when calculating areas.